# how to disallow uses of Naggy mocks in gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

gmock has 3 types of mocks, described here: https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#NiceStrictNaggy and here: https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#uninteresting-vs-unexpected

Summary:

- An uinteresting call is a call to a function which was never specified to be called.
- An unexpected call is a call to a function which had some expectations but none were matched.

All mocks treat unexpected calls as errors. Mocks differ how they treat unintersting calls:

- (default) naggy mock: print warning and return default value
- nice mock: return default value
- strict mock: fail the test

Default value is by default a default-constructed object (can be overriden - https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/mocking.html#DefaultValue). If not possible and not overriden, the test fails.

In short, naggy mock (at least for projects I work on) is the worst of both: it implements default behavior but prints warnings. I don't want warnings.

Gmock recommends: "to use nice mocks (not yet the default) most of the time, use naggy mocks (the current default) when developing or debugging tests, and use strict mocks only as the last resort."

I would like to disallow Naggy mocks in the project. Is there a clean way of doing it so that it can be enforced easily on CI but at the same time not limiting developers if they want to use it for debugging (uncommited changes)?

Comment: Send out a memo to the team that says "Naggy mocks are disallowed in the project."  Perhaps have a git hook to grep for Naggy mocks and auto-reject PRs that try to submit a Naggy mock.

Comment: That was my initial thought but I seek a more precise solution. Also, you can't grep for Naggy mocks because they are the default. Only Strict and Nice mocks are explicitly visible.

Comment: Do not overengineer this. Current default behavior is IMHO reasonable. Changing default behavior for whole project is asking for trouble. Do it for each test suite. If you like to take a risk, you can try play with gtest listener http://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events it should be possible to customize reports of uninteresting mock calls